# Group by but preserve statistical probability of value in limit

Tags: mysql

Consider a table in which a specific column is not unique:

```
name   
--------
john
paul
paul
george
ringo
paul
paul
paul
paul
```

How might one return *N* users by random, but preserve the statistical likelyhood that the user with the most entries is most likely to be returned? This would be similar to actually **drawing *N* names by way of slips of paper from a hat**, with the stipulation that if I draw a slip with the same name as one already drawn that I would discard it and draw another.

If I use `GROUP BY` and `LIMIT`, then MySQL *first* removes the dupes, *then* performs the limit. Note also that there are many fields returned, so using `DISTINCT` on the field list is not an option.

Of course, I would prefer to do this is a single query and not loop over a query. Note also that the database *might* contain less than *N* entries, in which case obviously each unique user will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

That was a challenge.  I think this will do the job:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (
     name VARCHAR(99)  NOT NULL,   -- this datatype should match your `name`
     rnd DOUBLE  NOT NULL
)
    SELECT name, RAND() FROM your_table;

SELECT name, MIN(rnd) AS x
    FROM t
    GROUP BY name
    ORDER BY x
    LIMIT ... ;    -- Fill in the "N" you want
```